# Store PDF file in JS variable

Tags: javascript, php

Here comes the html code

```
<input type="text" class="txtbox" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="txtbox" placeholder="E-mail"id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" class="txtbox" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone" />
<input type="file" class="txtbox" name="file" id="resume">
<input name="submit" id="submitbutton1" value="Apply Now" type="button" onClick="submitbutton1()" class="txtbox">
```

and my js function is as follows

```
<script>
function submitbutton1() 
{
  console.log("here");
  var name=$("#name").val();
  console.log(name);
  var email=$("#email").val();
  console.log(email);
  var phone=$("#phone").val();
  console.log(phone);
  var tal={"name":name,"email":email,"phone": phone};
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "email.php",
   data: tal,    
  success: function(ch)
  {     
    console.log(ch); 
  }
});
}
</script>
```

I would like to store the value of that pdf file into a js variable so that I can post all these variables into email.php Is it possible to store a pdf file in a js variable? If it is possible how? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your script.

```
<script>
function submitbutton1() 
{
  console.log("here");
  var name=$("#name").val();
  console.log(name);
  var email=$("#email").val();
  console.log(email);
  var phone=$("#phone").val();
  console.log(phone);
var resume=$("#resume").val();
  var tal={"name":name,"email":email,"phone": phone,"resume":resume};
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "email.php",
   data: tal,    
  success: function(ch)
  {     
    console.log(ch); 
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can store pdf value inside of your js variable, if you will have this value. You can do it using ajax call to load pdf document from your server. But, it will be binary data, and you will no be able to display it in browser to your client.
2. You can post this value to server, but it have no sense, because you can post only path to this file, and get content of this file using some server-side programming language functions (file_get_contents in your case).
3. There is no sense to send binary data as email content, so you should send it as attachment. Have no idea, is it possible to send attachment with php mail() function, previously I do it only with phpmailer. Php mailer need no your binary data, it require only path to file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to upload PDF file with ajax and post data into ajax using one ajax request. You can use FormData() object for post file and data value both

```
function submitbutton1() {
    var file_data = $('#resume').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    form_data.append('name', $("#name").val());
    form_data.append('email', $("#email").val());
    form_data.append('phone', $("#phone").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'email.php',
        cache: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result); 
        }
    });
};
```